# Using "without" in http.proxy directive in Caddyfile in caddy

Tags: reverse-proxy, caddy, caddyfile

I'm using the caddy as a reverse proxy and the config is the

```
proxy /app http://myapp:8080 {
    transparent
    insecure_skip_verify
    without /app 
  }
```

http://myapp:8080 is an Web application.
Here the request https://caddy/myapp redirects the request correctly but getting an error in the Web application while loading.
But if make the call as https://caddy/myapp/ then it works correctly.

what is the reason behind this and how to over come this one ?

How do I strip only "app" in the configuration ?

for example :

```
 without app
```

Tried this but it isn't working .
Any help is really appreciated , Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like your your web application is the problem not caddy. Can you verify you are listening on `/` ?

Comment: Not listening to / in the caddy file .